# How to use __StringFromFile function with Beanshell Preprocessor

Tags: strong-parameters

How to use __StringFromFile function with Beanshell Preprocessor
For example, i have a text file which contains comma separated values as in the attachment.

[image]
I want to read data from these file and assign to variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read complete file and store it into one variable than paste

```
${__FileToString(C:/path,,Variable_Name)}
```

command in beanshell preprocessor and pass `${Variable_Name}` where you want to use it

But

If you want to read line by line than you can choose `__StringFromFile` function, you can also use csv data set config to fulfill you requirement, just change delimiter `,` to some other delimiter like `~` (As you mentioned your values are separated by comma). It will capture complete line and store into one variable

Refer [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) link for detailed information on Jmeter function